# How to fix a local transition that is not working?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have built a form message interface. Basically, there are messages like this:

```js
{
    content: 'You made a mistake in your first name',
    id: 1,
    path: 'fieldErrors.firstName'
}
```

I manage those messages with a `formMsgs` store, then I use it in the markup like this (Pug):

```
mixin form-messages(path)
    +each('$formMsgs as msg (msg.id)')
        +if('msg.path === "' + path + '"')
            FormMsg(
                formMsgs!='{formMsgs}',
                formId!='{msg.id}')
```

In the `FormMsg` component, I have this for JS:

```js
import {fade} from 'svelte/transition';

export let formMsgs;
export let formId;

$: msg = processStore($formMsgs, formId);

let processStore = (msgs, id) => {
    for (let msg of msgs) {
        if (msg.id === id) {
            return msg;
        }
    }
}

let handleClose = () => {
    formMsgs.deleteMsg(formId);
}
```

And this for Pug:

```
div(class!='{msg.className}', transition:fade|local!='{{duration: 500}}')
    | {msg.content}
    .close(on:click!='{handleClose}') ✕
```

It works well, but the `transition:fade|local` is not applied. And I don't want to have a global transition as it creates problems when changing page.

I have found [this Github issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/628#issuecomment-1342393920), but it has been closed.

Any idea how to fix this? I might reopen this issue if needed.

Comment: The element has to be in a block that adds the element, e.g. `{#if}` or `{#each}`, is that the case or is there something else around the div?

Comment: I suspect that the `if` in the `each` causes interference...

Comment: @H.B. You are probably right about the `if`. The problem is that I have several spaces in my form and I need to filter which space each message go to.

I guess I could create a store for each space and use a store manager or something like that, I will try that.

Comment: Update: I tried creating a store manager, it does not work due to the `$myStore` syntax, you cannot use `$myStoreManager(arg)` in the template. I also tried to use a store that works with a `{path: [messages]}` structure. It works functionally, but the local transition it still not applied. I don't see any option at the moment and I will create a ticket about this on github.

Comment: I created an issue on github: [link](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/10417)

Answer (score 0):

I still have not found a fully satisfying solution and, IMO, [the Github issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/10417) is still relevant.

However, I changed two things:

- Rather than using an `if` to check the path, I use a store that accepts path as property
- Rather than using a `FormMsg` component and closing it from there, I call the closing function directly from the main component

In the end, I have this (this is Pug):

```
mixin form-messages(path)
    - let msgs = '$messageStore["' + path + '"]'
    +if(msgs)
        +each(msgs + ' as msg (msg.id)')
            .form-message(
                class!='{msg.className}', transition:fade|local!='{{duration: 500}}')
                | {msg.content}
                .close(on:click!='{() => messageStore.deleteMsg(msg.id)}') ✕
```

I have a transition when I manually close a message, but none when it's created.